# Jax vectorization: vmap and/or numpy.vectorize?

Tags: python, jax

what are the differences between `jax.numpy.vectorize`and `jax.vmap`?
Here is a small snipset

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

def f(x):
     return jnp.exp(-x)*jnp.sin(x)

gf = jax.grad(f)
x = jnp.arange(0,1,0.1)

jax.vmap(gf)(x)
jnp.vectorize(gf)(x)
```

Both computations give the same results:

DeviceArray([ 1.        ,  0.80998397,  0.63975394,  0.4888039 ,
0.35637075,  0.24149445,  0.14307144,  0.05990037,
-0.00927836, -0.06574923], dtype=float32)

How to decide which one to use, and if there is a  difference in terms of performance?

Answer (score 10):

`jax.vmap` and `jax.numpy.vectorize` have quite different semantics, and only happen to be similar in the case of a single 1D input as in your example.

The purpose of `jax.vmap` is to map a function over one or more inputs along **a single explicit axis**, as specified by the `in_axes` parameter. On the other hand, `jax.numpy.vectorize` maps a function over one or more inputs along **zero or more implicit axes** according to numpy broadcasting rules.

To see the difference, let's pass two 2-dimensional inputs and print the shape within the function:

```python
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

def print_shape(x, y):
  print(f"x.shape = {x.shape}")
  print(f"y.shape = {y.shape}")
  return x + y

x = jnp.zeros((20, 10))
y = jnp.zeros((20, 10))

_ = jax.vmap(print_shape)(x, y)
# x.shape = (10,)
# y.shape = (10,)

_ = jnp.vectorize(print_shape)(x, y)
# x.shape = ()
# y.shape = ()
```

Notice that `vmap` only maps along the first axis, while `vectorize` maps along *both* input axes.

And notice also that the implicit mapping of `vectorize` means it can be used much more flexibly; for example:

```python
x2 = jnp.arange(10)
y2 = jnp.arange(20).reshape(20, 1)

def add(x, y):
  # vectorize always maps over all axes, such that the function is applied elementwise
  assert x.shape == y.shape == ()
  return x + y

jnp.vectorize(add)(x2, y2).shape
# (20, 10)
```

`vectorize` will iterate over all axes of the inputs according to numpy broadcasting rules. On the other hand, `vmap` cannot handle this by default:

```python
jax.vmap(add)(x2, y2)
# ValueError: vmap got inconsistent sizes for array axes to be mapped:
# arg 0 has shape (10,) and axis 0 is to be mapped
# arg 1 has shape (20, 1) and axis 0 is to be mapped
# so
# arg 0 has an axis to be mapped of size 10
# arg 1 has an axis to be mapped of size 20
```

To accomplish this same operation with `vmap` requires more thought, because there are two separate mapped axes, and some of the axes are broadcast. But you can accomplish the same thing this way:

```python
jax.vmap(jax.vmap(add, in_axes=(None, 0)), in_axes=(0, None))(x2, y2[:, 0]).shape
# (20, 10)
```

This latter nested `vmap` is essentially what is happening under the hood when you use `jax.numpy.vectorize`.

As for which to use in any given situation:

- if you want to map a function across a single, explicitly specified axis of the inputs, use `jax.vmap`
- if you want a function's inputs to be mapped across zero or more axes according to numpy's broadcasting rules as applied to the input, use `jax.numpy.vectorize`.
- in situations where the transforms are identical (for example when mapping a function of 1D inputs) lean toward using `vmap`, because it more directly does what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks @jakevdp do you mean that for nD inputs (n>1) there is some cases where vectorize is better? or vmap should be used also?

Comment: Not better, but different. If you want your inputs to be broadcast according to numpy broadcasting rules, use vectorize. If you want your function to be mapped across a single specific axis of the inputs, use vmap.

Comment: I edited my answer to add more context - hope that helps!

Comment: Ho! Thanks a lot @jakevdp your enriched answer is very enlightening.